# extend() function in python reversing the elements while extending a list with a set of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, extend

Normal working of extend method

```
stack=[]
stack.extend("1")
stack.extend("2")
stack.extend("3")
print(stack)
>>['1', '2', '3']
```

Now let us try to extend this list with a set

```
set1 = set(['B','C'])
stack.extend(set1)
print(stack) 
>>['1', '2', '3', 'C', 'B']
```

Why is set getting appended as 'C' and then 'B' and not 'B' and'C' instead.I am expecting an output of ['1', '2', '3', 'B', 'C']

Comment: Because `set` is an inherently unordered data structure.

Comment: Hi @MustafaAydın. Thanks, I found another thread and now I know why. However , I found multiple implementations of DFS and BFS in python using this set and assuming it reverses every time you extend. Don't know how long will that implementation last, but sure helps for the time being.

Comment: @ImmortanJoe that implementation **is wrong**. `set` objects will not, in general, in any Python version, reverse a list. you are relying on *pure luck* if you rely on `set` reversing the order of a list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Got it. Thanks for the reply.